# Preventing memory leaks in consequtive allocator.allocate(...) statements

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, allocator

Please have a look at the following class:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename AllocA = std::allocator<A>, typename AllocB = std::allocator<B>>
class cls {
public:
    cls(size_t size) :
        size{ size },
        a{ alloc_a.allocate(size) },
        b1{ alloc_b.allocate(size) },
        b2{ alloc_b.allocate(size) }
    {}

    void reallocate() {
        alloc_a.deallocate(a, size);
        alloc_b.deallocate(b1, size);
        alloc_b.deallocate(b2, size);

        a = alloc_a.deallocate(size);
        b1 = alloc_b.deallocate(size);
        b2 = alloc_b.deallocate(size);
    }

    ~cls() {
        alloc_a.deallocate(a, size);
        alloc_b.deallocate(b1, size);
        alloc_b.deallocate(b2, size);
    }

private:
    size_t size;

    AllocA alloc_a;
    AllocB alloc_b;

    A* a;
    B* b1;
    B* b2;
};
```

I want to rewrite this class in a way, that properly prevents memory leaks, when some allocator's `allocate` or `deallocate` method throws an exception. I am aware of [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and generally the concept of [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). However, I

1. do not see how to use `std::unique_ptr` in a class supporting custom allocators, and
2. want to keep the class memory-wise *as small as possible*, disallowing me to outsource the pointers to dedicated RAII-classes with individual allocators or references to a shared allocator.

Additionally, I need the first allocation to happen in the initializer list, since in the real use case, the pointer members are actually `const` in *some* specializations of the template.

Now, these are a lot of requirements and expectations, but since we're talking C++ here, I feel like there is still a way, to archive this. Or do I actually need to make some cuts on my requirements?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` can have a custom deleter, so you could write a class that stores a pointer or reference to an allocator and overload `operator()` to call `deallocate`.

Comment: Thanks, that already answer bullet point 1. However, in this case for each pointer I would have an additional reference to the allocator, increasing the size of my class.

Comment: @IlCapitano Is that actually possibe, though? As far as I can see, `std::unique_ptr` would need its deleter to be default-constructible, which does not apply to a lambda type.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the members being `const` in some specializations since all members are `private` in your example, so you can just not change them in your member functions.  If this is really a requirement I don't really see a way to be exception safe.

Comment: @IlCapitano it should be `const` in dependence of some boolean template argument I omitted here, because depending on that argument it *will be* `const`. Making it non-`const` just to be able to set it in constructor may be practical but is not as 'precise' as it could be. I know I am kinda idealistic there.